# blazor.server.js 404 not found

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I have an existing ASP.NET Core (.NET 5) application and I wanted to integrate Blazor to it, so I added the below configuration to the Startup.cs file inside the `ConfigureServices` function:

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

Inside the `Configure` method that runs at runtime, I've defined the endpoints configuration like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{

    // Omitted some code just for brevity
    [...]
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();

}
```

I have defined `app.UseStaticFiles()` and even included `webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets()` inside the `Program.cs` file as well.

Inside the `_Layout.cshtml` file I defined the `<base href="~/" />` tag inside the `<head>` tag and also I included the `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`   tag

When I compile my solution I notice the `_framework` folders is not being generated anywhere and when I run the application I always get `https://localhost:{port}/_framework/blazor.server.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`. Another thing I notice is, if I navigate to `https://localhost:{port}/_blazor` I get `Connection ID required` as a response but I'm not sure if this means the signalR server for the Blazor component is running or not as I do not see the `negotiate` request under the Network tab when I inspect the Dev Tools window.

I tried several things to make this work but none of them did so far. I've read several tutorials on how to add Blazor to MVC projects, and I've taken examples from Github that I tried to follow extensively but without success. At this point, I'm running out of options.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: adding more context for the `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` files below:

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

{
    CustomConfigureServices(services, Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<MyDataProtection>();

 

    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

 

    services.AddMvc(options => {
        options.Filters.Add(new CustomActionFilter());
    });
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        //options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;

        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;

        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;

        // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1

        options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();

    });
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => {
        options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    });

    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>

            {

                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");

            });

 

            services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, AddRolesClaimsTransformation>();

 

            string _pluginsPath = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}Plugins";

 

            string[] _pluginsDlls = Directory.GetFiles(_pluginsPath).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".plugin.dll", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToArray();

 

            List<Assembly> _pluginsAssemblies = new();

 

            foreach (string _dll in _pluginsDlls)

            {

                Assembly _pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(_dll);

 

                if (_pluginAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IPlugin))).Any())

                {

                    _pluginsAssemblies.Add(_pluginAssembly);

                }

            }

 

            foreach (Assembly item in _pluginsAssemblies)

            {

                services.AddControllersWithViews()

                    .AddApplicationPart(item)

                    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

 

 

                services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>

                { options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(item)); });

            }

 

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>

                        {

                            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

                            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                            options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();

                            //see: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/334 https://xtremeownage.com/2021/11/10/asp-net-core-links-dont-work-from-office-word-document-to-sso-site/

                            options.Events.OnRemoteFailure += OnRemoteFailureFuncAsync;

                            options.Events.OnTokenValidated += OnTokenValidatedFuncAsync;

                        }

                    )

                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(

                        Configuration.GetSection("WebApplications:WebApplicationsScopes").Get<string>().Split(" ", System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

                        )

                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

 

            // Add APIs

            services.AddWebApplicationsService(Configuration);

 

            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(jsonOptions =>

            {

                jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();

            });

 

            // Add the Kendo UI services to the services container.

            services.AddKendo();

 

            //Configure Session

            services.AddSession(options =>

            {

                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40); //TODO get time for session 

                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>

            {

                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()

                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()

                    .Build();

                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

 

            services.AddRazorPages();

 

            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>

            {

                options.EnableForHttps = true;

            });

 

            ConfigureBlazorComponents(services, _pluginsAssemblies);

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {
            app.UseSession();
            if (!env.IsProduction())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

 

            app.UseCatchSecurityExceptionsMiddleware();

 

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            var cacheMaxAgeOneWeek = (60 * 60 * 24 * 7).ToString();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append(
                         "Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cacheMaxAgeOneWeek}");
                }
            });
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseResponseCompression();
            app.UseRouting();

 

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

 

            IDictionary<string, string> _appSettings = ConfigurationHelper.AppSettings;
            string defaultController;
            _appSettings.TryGetValue("DefaultController", out defaultController);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultController))
            {
                defaultController = ApplicationConfig.DefaultController;
            }

 

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "landingpage",
                    pattern: "LandingPage",
                    defaults: new { controller = "LandingPage", action = "Index" });

 

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "menuPlugin",
                    pattern: "Menu{ControllerPlugin}.{ActionPlugin}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", ControllerPlugin = ApplicationConfig.DefaultController, ActionPlugin = ApplicationConfig.DefaultAction });

 

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

 

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "showAnnotation",
                   pattern: "ShowAnnotation",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShowAnnotation" });

 

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "comesFromPortal",
                   pattern: "ComesFromPortal",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ComesFromPortal" });


                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();

 

                lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(CloseAndFlushLog); //register callback to flush pending log events before shutdown

 

            });
}
```

The `ConfigureBlazorComponents(services, _pluginsAssemblies)` function is where I'm doing the `services.AddServerSideBlazor()` part

*Program.cs*

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerilogSetup.Setup();
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
             webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();
             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Comment: See this article which explains how to add Blazor to the standard Razor template - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321697/Building-a-Blazor-Server-Application-from-the-Web.  Make it work form the standard templates first, and then go back to your site and figure out what's different.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I appreciate the response. Thank you for the article but I also followed that one, no luck so far. It is still the same error, I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, this is how Blazor components are supposed to be added to existing MVC projects. I also defined `services.AddServerSideBlazor(o => o.DetailedErrors = true)` to see if I can get detailed error messages but it seems the SignalR server is not even instantiated. I don't know, I'm very lost

Comment: What does your startup (_Hosts) page look like?

Comment: This could be as simple as a caching issue. Try clearing the cache in the browser after your changes.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis it's an MVC project, it doesn't have a _Hosts file. It has a _Layout.cshml and _Index.cshtml files, however. I posted above what I did for the _Layout file to add the blazor.server.js script.

Comment: @BrianParker I did that as well. Clearing the cache is not the issue at the moment.

Comment: Just noticed It's Net 5, so we have the split in cshtml files.  Have you tried changing endpoints out for app, so you have `app.MapRazorPages()`.  My best guess is that the endpoint delivering your page doesn't have the correct middleware configured,  A more complete view of `Program` might help.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis exactly, is a .NET 5 project, it has both Program.cs and Startup.cs files. I'll edit the question to add more information about both files.

Comment: Where you want to include the blazor codes? Directly inside the view?  You want to put the blazor app inside the MVC view?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I'm putting the blazor component inside the MVC view. The blazor code is on its own file and is served through its own _Index.cshtml file by using the `Html.RenderComponentAsync` (I also tried using the `<component>` tag for that) with `RenderMode.ServerPrerendered`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's help. I finally found the reason behind this error, and the problem was located inside the `Configure` function where we were making use of the `app.UseStaticFiles()`. To be more specific here's the portion of the code that was causing the `blazor.server.js` file to be 404'd:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={cacheMaxAgeOneWeek}");
    }
});
```

Refer to this GitHub issue for more information -- [Passing options to UseStaticFiles breaks Blazor Server's static file service](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19578). But basically, by passing any kind of `StaticFileOptions` object to `app.UseStaticFiles()`, then Blazor Server will no longer be able to serve `blazor.server.js` file even if you have configured everything correctly.

In order to avoid this add `app.UseStaticFiles()` without any parameters, and below define as many `app.UseStaticFiles()` as you need if you need any specific configuration for your static files, based on my own testings and the GitHub issue this is possible. Hope this helps.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Please mark it as answer so that other folks who face the same issue, could find the answer more easily. Thanks.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I cannot accept my own answer yet. I'll be able to do that in 5 hours.