# blazor.server.js not found and returned ERR::ABORTED, how to solve?

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

I met this error with all settings in Startup.cs correctly, (kind of). and _Host.cshtml also normal. I've read the passage at [blazor.server.js 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77130208/blazor-server-js-404-not-found) and tried to do as same, not working for me.

But something maybe affect my project is, I caught all routers at Index.razor with @page "/{*param}".  But not likely, because _content/mudblazor.min.js still reachable. I've asked New bing and it responded me useless stuff, and cannot be applied in my code.

And what's more, I saw the browser do trying to get the blazor.server.js, and it do get something only 55B, this shouldn't be something useful.

I tried methods in [blazor.server.js 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77130208/blazor-server-js-404-not-found), and also tried to modify UseEndpoints and MapFallbackToPage(suggested by new bing)...

these just not working.

and, btw, I tried to ban some requests by using code:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{

    OnPrepareResponse = s =>
    {
        s.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public, max-age={(60 * 60 * 24 * 7).ToString()}");
        if (s.Context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/Sharlog")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BLOCK CRIT. ACCESS");
            s.Context.Response.StatusCode = 418;
            s.Context.Response.Body = Stream.Null;
            s.Context.Response.ContentLength = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

(uh, how to clarify to this code block that this is C#?)

--- update: add detailed my _Host.cshtml:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Shared
@namespace Sharlog.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    @* <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> *@
    <environment include="Staging, Development">
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment include="Production">
        <link />
        @*universal Tailwind CSS*@
    </environment>
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />*@
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Sharlog.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />


</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
@* @Body render start here ^ *@

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <BlazorErrUI />
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code formatting is inferred from the tag. You can also manually specify the language of the code block e.g. ```cs ``` stands for C#. SO uses highlight.js https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md

Comment: Can you share your `_Host.cshtml`

Comment: @MarvinKlein   here I'm updating question. please take a review

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<base href="/" />` in your `<head>` content.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-the-app-base-path for more information.

Comment: I've modified it as you suggested. but it appeared the same error.

Comment: Open the browser dev tools and look at the network traffic to see where the browser is trying to retrieve the JavaScript file from.

You could also try using `<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`